# Differences between conclusions from a p-value and confidence intervals

Tags: confidence-interval, p-value, survey

I have an issue with a result I just found.

I ran a sub-population analysis (for 2 age groups) with a complex survey design.

For this purpose I fitted a generalized linear model (family:normal,link:identity), using the function `svyglm` from the R package `survey`.

Here is my code for the model:

```
model=svyglm(score ~ DLA +relevel(sex,2)+raeth+pir+age+educa+(DLA:re‌​level(sex,2)),
               design,data=imp1)
```

DLA is my exposure of interest and was included as categorical (tertiles)

For one of my sub-population analyses (for older age group), my results suggest a significant difference of **(-7.50 (95% CI:-14.54, -0.46))** between the third tertile and the first tertile of exposure), but the **p-value=0.058** suggested a non significant result.

There is not such a big difference, but I wonder how it could be possible that **the confidence interval does not include 0, whereas the p-value suggests a non-significant result**.

Thank you very much for your answers

Comment: Can you clarify the model you fitted please? Its very hard to tell what things we're comparing here.

Comment: I fitted a generalized additive model. If you need further informations, please tell me. Here is my code for the model: model=svyglm(score~DLA_tert+relevel(sex,2)+raeth+pir_4+age_yr+educa+(DLA_tert:relevel(sex,2)),design,data=base_imp1)
Thank you

Comment: I can't tell *what* CI and *what* test, using which approximations or assumptions, you might be getting. What is the family and link, at least? (What software? What commands?)

Comment: Sorry, it was a generalized linear model with family: normal and identity link in R. I putted the code in the first comment

Comment: It's probably better to put all this information in the question itself.

Comment: Ah I didn't see the code in the comment; my subsequent response was written before you edited that comment to put it in. But in any case, it should not be necessary to read all the comments to understand the question.

Comment: I added all informations in the question. thank you for your help

Comment: I've never heard of the `svyglm` function. What package is that in?

Comment: It's the package survey of Professor Thomas Lumley

Comment: When you edit to include that information, could you remove your name from the question, please? See the help [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/behavior), under the heading **Do not use signature, taglines, or greetings**.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11571/discussion-between-you-safe-and-glen-b)

Answer (score 2):

Both should be considered as ''borderline''... this is not *so* surprising.

Are you familiar with likelihood theory, and the three tests? Assuming it is the case, assume that the confidence interval is a Wald confidence interval, and that the $p$-value is obtained from a score test or a likelihood ratio test. *Asymptotically*, you will have $p < 0.05$ if, and only if, $0$ is not in the confidence interval, but for small samples you can meet an exception from time.

More generally, the confidence interval and the $p$-value can be obtained by procedures which are not exactly the dual of each other. This example (generated after a few trials) exhibits a similar behavior:

```
> x <- c(7, 3, 6, 7, 8, 4, 4, 3, 10, 5)
> y <- c(9, 19, 5, 12, 9, 13, 7, 19, 11, 7)
>  fit <- glm(y~x, family=poisson)
> summary(fit)

Call:
glm(formula = y ~ x, family = poisson)

Deviance Residuals: 
     Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max  
-1.92492  -1.15183   0.06332   1.07970   1.31742  

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)  2.88977    0.25941  11.140   <2e-16 ***
x           -0.08786    0.04557  -1.928   0.0539 .  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1 


> confint(fit)
                 2.5 %       97.5 %
(Intercept)  2.3732479  3.391536328
x           -0.1791838 -0.000207765
```

Comment: Thank you ELvis for your response, Do you how to extract the employed method to calculate both p-value and confidence intervals in R. Just to ensure that what you proposed as an explanation is what is happening here.

Comment: If the documentation (or the package vignette) don’t tell you what procedure is used for the test or for the confidence interval, the only thing to do is to look at the functions code to find it...