# Discordant significance of OR’s confidence interval and p-value in glm(quasibinomial) model [R]

Tags: generalized-linear-model, p-value, odds-ratio, quasi-likelihood, profile-likelihood

I’m currently trying to test if differences in proportions of people infected by malaria (RDT positive) between clusters with high or low coverage of control intervention are significant. Therefore I’m running a quasi-binomial GLM in R like this:

```
fit <- glm(cbind(RDT_pos, RDT_neg)~ Coverage_ov75 + rur_urb + pattern, data=df, quasibinomial)
```

My explanatory variable of interest is `Coverage_ov75`; the others are controlling variables. Everything is ok until I test the significance. When I use `summary(fit)`, p-value is 0.0630, so the result is non significant at .05 level:

```
Call:
glm(formula = cbind(RDT_pos, RDT_neg) ~ Coverage_ov75 + rur_urb + 
pattern, family = quasibinomial, data = df)

Deviance Residuals: 
Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-3.7111  -1.9594  -0.7794   1.0525   3.8943  

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)       -5.1581     0.7147  -7.217 7.48e-07 ***
Coverage_ov751    -1.4263     0.7224  -1.975   0.0630 .  
rur_urb1           0.3906     0.5999   0.651   0.5227    
patternHighlands   1.3138     0.7581   1.733   0.0993 .  
patternSouth       1.6602     0.7000   2.372   0.0284 *  
patternWest        1.3084     0.7271   1.799   0.0878 .  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for quasibinomial family taken to be 5.131962)

Null deviance: 157.92  on 24  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 103.30  on 19  degrees of freedom
AIC: NA

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 5
```

But when I use odds ratios’ 95% confidence intervals, the result becomes significant –i.e. 95%CI excludes 1.00 value-, whether I use `confint` or `confint.default` function:

```
> exp(cbind(coef(fit), confint(fit)))  
Waiting for profiling to be done...
                                  2.5 %      97.5 %
(Intercept)      0.005752403 0.00115120  0.01973567
Coverage_ov751   0.240198126 0.04344154  0.83777344
rur_urb1         1.477932315 0.47495969  5.29358843
patternHighlands 3.720230839 0.83163497 18.19418962
patternSouth     5.260253952 1.37407939 23.72815126
patternWest      3.700344766 0.91283718 17.44061487
> exp(cbind(coef(fit), confint.default(fit)))  
                                    2.5 %      97.5 %
(Intercept)      0.005752403 0.001417273  0.02334774
Coverage_ov751   0.240198126 0.058304544  0.98954790
rur_urb1         1.477932315 0.456059336  4.78947312
patternHighlands 3.720230839 0.841872843 16.43967686
patternSouth     5.260253952 1.334015707 20.74208834
patternWest      3.700344766 0.889853675 15.38741905
```

The result from confint.default is very close to significance level but the p-value is not so close to .05, at least not as much as what I previously observed in discrepant results (or as others describe e.g. in [Differences between conclusions from a p-value and confidence intervals](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/76930/differences-between-conclusions-from-a-p-value-and-confidence-intervals)) .

I’m not used to quasi-binomial models, so I wonder if my procedure correct. If it’s correct, than how should I interpret these discrepant results?